# Cucumber Ruby - Spaces in cucumber.yml profile ENV variables

Tags: ruby, cucumber, environment-variables, browserstack

I'm using ruby to script my cucumber tests and have hit a problem when defining some variables.

I need to run a test on the iPhone 6 device, so I added the following (BrowserStack) definition into my cucumbers env.rb file;

```
capabilities['device'] = ENV['MOBILE_DEVICE']
```

And the following profile into my cucumber.yml file;

```
bsmobile: BROWSER_NAME=iPhone PLATFORM=MAC MOBILE_DEVICE='iPhone 6'
```

However, when I run this on Windows it's not allowing the space in the 'MOBILE_DEVICE' env.

I've tried;

```
MOBILE_DEVICE="iPhone 6"
"MOBILE_DEVICE=iPhone 6"
MOBILE_DEVICE="'iPhone 6'"
MOBILE_DEVICE='iPhone\ 6'
MOBILE_DEVICE=iPhone\ 6
```

But none seemed to work.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Where does the key `bsmobile` come from? Who is parsing that key from the Yaml file?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that the 'bsmobile' is just a cucumber profile name (I've given when testing) for the testing of the mobile device (in this cast iPhone 6. So when I run the cucumber test I only need to enter '-p bsmobile' rather than all of the environments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just pass the device as iPhone6 with a space. The same should work for iPhone6S and other mobile emulators. Have you tried this already?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found on [line 34 of the cucumber gem file `profile_loader.rb`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/f5a396aba2bba85af65685b2577bc9253e303bd6/lib/cucumber/cli/profile_loader.rb#L34):

```
args_from_yml = Shellwords.shellwords(args_from_yml)
```

From here we can test to see what works in irb, and after a little experimentation we find this:

```
Shellwords.shellwords("xxx yyy zzz=\'aaa bbb\'")
=> ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz=aaa bbb"]
```

Hence the solution to your problem should be:

```
MOBILE_DEVICE='iPhone 6'
```